# Can I use a third party mail server instead of mail services offered by the domain registrar web host?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, email

I am looking at buying a domain with 1&1 and web hosting with HostPresto. Hostpresto offer unlimited email addresses on the domain but 1&1 only have 1. Is it possible to use HostPresto's email servers but on the domain registered with 1&1.

E.g: I buy mywebsite.com from 1&1 and then set DNS up to redirect to my HostPresto web server. Can I get name@mywebsite.com to be set up from HostPresto or does it have to be the 1&1 one?

Plans I'm buying:

- Starter Hosting plan from https://hostpresto.com/web-hosting/
- Domain from https://www.1and1.co.uk/domain-names#your-domain

Answer (score 1):

If your domain is pointing to the right nameserver then you can you the mail server from your hosting provider.
Also, you can point your MX records to a third party mail server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if and how you control your DNS zone content (and basically if you can put the MX record of your choosing or not).

You are paying two providers for their service, so you should probably ask them for help first.

Answer (score 0):

To use a third party mail server, you need to be able to change the DNS MX records for the domain.   The MX record points to the IP address of the mail server.

Most domain registrars that offer web hosting and DNS hosting allow you to add DNS records and change the MX settings.   They may be some that do not.

1&1 does allow the MX records to be edited.  They have instructions for that here: https://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/manage-domains-c79822/dns-c37586/editchange-the-domain-s-mail-servers-mx-record-a594907.html   You would just need to set the MX records to the IP addresses and priorities of the HostPresto mail servers. HostPresto will tell you this information.